# Filtrar registros dentro de um intervalo de um mês

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Tenho vários itens vendidos em um mês e gostaria de exibir só os itens
vendidos no mês atual.

Exemplo: no mês de setembro tive um total de 30 itens vendidos, e no mês de agosto, 20 itens.

Como pego a data atual e verifico a quantidade de itens vendidos no intervalo de um mês?

Estou usando Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

você pode fazer assim:

```
Model::whereMonth('created_at', '12'); // apenas o mês 12 (Dezembro)
Model::whereYear('created_at', '2018'); // apenas o ano 2018
Model::whereDay('created_at', '2018-12-31'); // apenas o dia
```

Lembrando que você pode combinar esses 3,

```
Model::whereMonth('created_at', '12')->whereYear('created_at', '2018');
```

Espero ter ajudado!